# Android glide error after activity was destroyed and restarted

Tags: android, android-glide

I get the following error when trying to load an image from assets into ImageView after app was closed and restarted:

```
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

The scenario in which this issue appears:

Android 5.0.1 (also tried on 5.1.1 - same issue)

1. Start app
2. Load animated image from assets into ImageView (image is loaded fine)
3. Make sure activity is destroyed
4. Restart activity
5. Try to load same image - get the above-mentioned errors

However, if I don't load image in step 2, but just close and restart app, and load image in step 5, there is no error - image is loaded fine.

Here is my code for loading image:

```
Glide.with(applicationContext)
                .using(new AssetUriLoader(applicationContext))
                .load(Uri.parse(assetPath))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

The AssetUriLoader is a custom loader suggested by vpratfr in the following ticket:

[Loading images from assets](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/155)

The ImageView is created programmatically:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mImageViewWidth, mImageViewHeigh);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    params.leftMargin = 100;
    params.topMargin = 100;
    rl.addView(imageView, params);
```

If someone had this error after app is restarted, and found a solution, help would be much appreciated.